# Where do Start Menu\All Programs shortcuts reside?

Tags: windows-7, windows, shortcuts, start-menu

What is the Windows 7 equivalent of each these Windows XP locations?

- `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\`
- `C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Start Menu\Programs\`
- `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\`
- `C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\`

Thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As you edited -

Any users start menu is located at:

> C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\

So for your example, it would be:

> C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\

And the Global / All users Start Menu is located at:

> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs

All users / Default Desktop is now a hidden folder located at:

> C:\Users\Public\Desktop

Any users desktop is located at

> C:\Users\USER-NAME\Desktop\

So for your example, if the user is administrator, it would be:

> C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\

But if it is the current logged on user, a quicker way is simply to type this in to run or the explorer bar:

> %userprofile%\desktop

Comment: Remember you can also right-click a folder in the Start Menu and select Open for the current user's folder, or Open All Users for the shared folder.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the path where Windows 7 stores links that you "Pinned To Start Menu"

- C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick
  Launch\User Pinned\StartMenu

Answer (score 4):

All Users' Start Menu:

- `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\`

Administrator's Start Menu:

- `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\`

All Users' Desktop:

- `C:\Users\Public\Desktop\`

Administrator's Desktop:

- `C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\`